# How many ways can the owner of the cinema choose $3$ teams of workers given that he has $50$ workers available?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

> Question : One cinema has $3$ rooms (A,B,C).  Room A needs $6$ workers inside, B needs $5$ workers and C needs $9$ workers.  How many ways can the owner of the cinema choose $3$ teams of workers given that he has $50$ workers available?

What I did is:

I can have  $6 \cdot 5 \cdot 9 =270$.  I know that $n=50$ and $r=3$ so

$C(n,r) = \dfrac{n!}{r!(n−r)!} = 19600$.

$19600-270=18930$.

Did I solve it right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first group, A, needs 6 people. There are $\binom{50}{6}$ ways to do so.

The second group, B, needs 5 people. There are $\binom{50-6}{5}$ = $\binom{44}{5}$ ways to do so.

The second group, C, needs 9 people. There are $\binom{50-6-5}{9}$ = $\binom{39}{9}$ ways to do so.

Finally, there are $\binom{50}{6} \cdot \binom{44}{5} \cdot \binom{39}{9}$ ways to assign the workers into three groups.